# Add seperate image for each price of product in stripe

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I want to add image to each of my `price` (plan) in stripe. I know I could add an image to the product but I don't want this.
Basically I have 3 `plans` for my `product` (e.g. Single device, 3 devices and 7 devices )
and I want to add image representing 1, 3 and 7 devices respectively to show on the front-end.

Is it really possible in `stripe` without hardcoding images mapped with product IDs on my front-end?

Answer (score 1):

Stripe Products represent the thing people are buying, and Prices represent how they can pay for Products.  You can only set an image on Products in Stripe because the thing you're buying doesn't change based on the Price (if it does, you should model that as a separate Product).

As an example, imagine a Product that represents a chair with two Prices: a normal price and a discount price.  The image of the chair associated with the Product doesn't change based on the price; it's still the same chair.

You can specify custom images based on Prices, but you would need to do that on your end, not inside Stripe.